# How to randomly replace a value

Tags: r, if-statement, random

I have a vector of a certain length of which I want to randomly replace every 2 by 0 or 1, with a probability of 0.4 (for value=1). I have used this code below. I expected to have a different value (0 or 1) for the different 2 replaced, but I have only 1 or 0 that replace the 2.

```
vec<-c(rep(2,18),1,0)

ifelse (vec==2,rbinom(1,1,0.40)
```

here is one output

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

and another output

```
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: If you draw a `0` you want the value to remain `2`?

Comment: Yes, both possibilities will do the job. If I draw 0, the value remains 2, does the job. But if I draw 0, and the value is 0, also do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go into the source code of `ifelse` via typing `View(ifelse)`, you will see a piece of code showing that

```
    len <- length(ans)
    ypos <- which(test)
    npos <- which(!test)
    if (length(ypos) > 0L) 
        ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos]
    if (length(npos) > 0L) 
        ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos]
    ans
```

That means, once you have one single value for `yes` or `no` in `ifelse`, that single value is repeated `len` times and placed to the corresponding logical positions.

In you case, `rbinom(1,1,0.40)` is just a single value for `yes`, thus being repeated once it has an realization.

---

One workaround is like below

```
> ifelse(vec == 2, rbinom(sum(vec == 2), 1, 0.40), vec)
 [1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: Cool. It is great

Answer (score 1):

This replaces all `2` values with either `0` or `1`

```
vec[vec == 2] <- rbinom(sum(vec == 2), 1, prob = .4)
```

If you draw a `0` and want the value to remain 2 then you could use `sample`, which would be equivalent to a binomial draw:

```
vec[vec == 2] <- sample(c(1, 2), sum(vec == 2), prob = c(0.4, 0.6), replace = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next code:

```
#Code
vec<-c(rep(2,18),1,0)
vec2 <- unlist(lapply(seq(2,length(vec),by=2), function(x) {vec[x] <- rbinom(1,1,0.40)}))
vec[seq(2,length(vec),by=2)] <-vec2
```

Output:

```
vec
 [1] 2 0 2 0 2 1 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 1 2 0 2 0 1 1
```